# Typeorm retry connectio on failure

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose, typeorm

I have a very simple `node.js` application, which communicates with the postgres database using `Typeorm`. It works fine if I run it on my host machine, or in two separate docker containers.
the problem occurred when I created a docker-compose file which starts Postgres and node application.Typeorm fails to connect to Postgres because it starts sooner. 
this is the part of the code which connects to DB

```js
createConnection({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 5432,
    username: "***",
    password: "***",
    database: "***",
    entities: [
        ***
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
}).then(async connection => {...
```

the error code message is

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
web_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
web_1  |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
web_1  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
web_1  |   port: 5432
web_1  | }
```

is there a way to retry the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that to connect Postgres DB from docker compose, you need to connect not to localhost, but to the service name that you provided in docker-compose.yaml file. for example here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: '***'
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '***'
          POSTGRES_DB: '***'
    ports:
          - 5432:5432
    expose: 
      - 5432
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
```

for this configuration for typeorm to connect to Postgres, I need to specify the connection properties like this

```
{
    type: "postgres",
    host: "",
    port: 5432,
    username: "***",
    password: "***",
    database: "***",
    entities: [
        ***
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
}
```